# join and null values rows not showing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have this statement:

```
SELECT personen.*, klassen.naam as klas FROM `personen` 
JOIN `klassen` ON `klassen`.id = `personen`.Id 
WHERE `rol` = "Docent" ORDER BY id
```

I know that it basically puts the column `klassen.naam` into `personen` by checking if the foreign key `K_Id` is the same as the id of Klassen:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/TNlMBpd.png]

In the table above I have 4 results, these are all the people who have a `K_Id` assigned, however there are 2 more people who have a `K_Id` of `null`:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/3IPX92E.png]

My problem is that when `K_Id` is `null` it doesn't return anything at all, which makes sense, I just don't know how to fix it.

My question is: How can i write the statement so that it still shows all the other rows  where the `K_Id` value is `null`?

Comment: Use a left join. - http://i.stack.imgur.com/1UKp7.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT personen.*, klassen.naam as klas 
FROM `personen` 
JOIN `klassen` 
ON `klassen`.id = `personen`.Id 
WHERE `rol` = "Docent" 
ORDER BY id
```

You should use left join if you want all of your data from personen Table where personen.id is not present in klassen table it look like this

```
    SELECT personen.*, klassen.naam as klas 
    FROM `personen` 
    LEFT JOIN `klassen` 
    ON `klassen`.id = `personen`.Id 
    WHERE `rol` = "Docent" 
    ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use a `left join` for this purpose.  Assuming `rol` is in the `personen` table:

```
SELECT p.*, k.naam as klas 
FROM `personen` p LEFT JOIN
     `klassen` i
     ON  i.id = p.Id 
WHERE p.`rol` = 'Docent'
ORDER BY p.id;
```

If `rol` is in the `klassen` table, then:

```
SELECT p.*, k.naam as klas 
FROM `personen` p LEFT JOIN
     `klassen` i
     ON  i.id = p.Id AND i.`rol` = 'Docent'
ORDER BY p.id;
```

Note that I also introduced table aliases in the query.  These make queries easier to write and to read.

Also, this will return all rows in the `personen` table (subject to the `where`), including non-matches.  If you just specifically wanted NULL values, then you would use:

```
SELECT p.*, k.naam as klas 
FROM `personen` p JOIN
     `klassen` i
     ON  i.id = p.Id or p.id is null
WHERE p.`rol` = 'Docent'
ORDER BY p.id;
```

I'm guessing you really want the `left join` version.